# Jenkins Job Builder error - TypeError: cannot serialize {'repo': None} (type dict)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to build my config.xml files for pushing into Jenkins using the Jenkins Job Builder and I face an error. Shown below is the project.yml file:

```
- project:
    name: my_nice_checkout_jobs
    repo:
        - scripts:
            branch_name: master
    jobs:
        - '_MY_NICE_JOB_JJB_checkout_{repo}'
```

I get an error as `TypeError: cannot serialize {'repo': None} (type dict)`. Why is repo None?? I have declared it above.